# Matrix, Drag and Drop Upload

Tags: matrix, channel-images

i'd like to combine Channel Images with Matrix, or at least a Drag and Drop File upload for a Matrix Field. I couldn't find anything like that, so maybe someone here can help

1. Is it possible to upload files/images to a matrix file field ?

If 1. is not possible, is it possible to drag and drop upload a file/image to a matrix file field ?

thanks for any help !!

Answer (score 0):

There is [Matrix Multi-Upload](https://devot-ee.com/add-ons/matrix-multi-upload) which would allow you to upload multiple images but I don't think it allows drag and drop functionality.

If you want drop and drag functionality I think you are limited to Channel Images or [Photo Frame](https://devot-ee.com/add-ons/photo-frame)